# How to escape a URL with a $ in a markdown link?

Tags: markdown

I am creating some technical documentation using markdown. What I need to do is to create a link to this page:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

So my link looks like this:

```
[$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)
```

This works just fine in every other link on the page, but in this case, the presence of $ in the URL is causing markdown to break. It generates this instead:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get markdown to ignore the $ in the URL?

I've tried using a slash and double slash before the $, and also tried tick marks around the $, but these did not seem to work as intended in this case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters?

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion GSerg, unfortunately, it did not work, however it did lead me to try using a character entity reference (&dollar;), and that did work! So, this... [&dollar;window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service&dollar;window)